# Mongodb Tailable Cursor in nodejs, how to stop stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I use below code to get the data from mongodb capped collection

function listen(conditions, callback) {

```
        db.openConnectionsNew( [req.session.client_config.db] , function(err, conn){

            if(err) {console.log({err:err}); return next(err);}

            coll = db.opened[db_name].collection('messages');

        latestCursor = coll.find(conditions).sort({$natural: -1}).limit(1)
        latestCursor.nextObject(function(err, latest) {
            if (latest) {
                conditions._id = {$gt: latest._id}
            }
            options = {
                tailable: true,
                awaitdata: true,
                numberOfRetries: -1
            }
            stream = coll.find(conditions, options).sort({$natural: -1}).stream()
            stream.on('data', callback)
        });

        });
    }
```

and then I use sockets.broadcast(roomName,'data',document);

on client side

```
io.socket.get('/get_messages/', function(resp){
});
io.socket.on('data', function notificationReceivedFromServer ( data ) {
  console.log(data);
```

});

this works perfectly as I am able to see the any new document which is inserted in db.

I can see in mongod -verbose  that after each 200ms there is query running with the query {$gt:latest_id} and this is fine, but I have no idea how can i close this query :( I am very new in nodejs and using the mongodb tailable option for the first time and am totally lost, any help or clue is highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is returned from the [`.stream()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#stream) method from the [Cursor](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html) object returned from [`.find()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#find) is an implementation of the [node transform stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) interface. Specifically this is a "readable" stream.

As such, it's "data" event is emitted whenever there is new data received and available in the stream to be read.

There are other methods such as [`.pause()`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pause) and [`.resume()`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_resume) which can be used to control the flow of these events. Typically you would call these "inside" a "data" event callback, where you wanted to make sure the code in that callback was executed before the "next" data event was processed:

```
stream.on("data", function(data) {
   // pause before processing
   stream.pause();

  // do some work, possibly with a callback
  something(function(err,result) {

      // Then resume when done
      stream.resume();
  });
});
```

But of course this is just a matter of "scoping". So as long as the "stream" variable is defined in a scope where another piece of code can access it, then you can call either method at any time.

Again, by the same token of scoping, you can just "undefine" the "stream" object at any point in the code, making the "event processing" redundant.

```
// Just overwrite the object
scope = undefined;
```

So worth knowing. In fact the newer "version 2.x" of the node driver wraps a "stream interface" directly into the standard `Cursor` object without the need to call `.stream()` to convert. Node streams are very useful and powerful things that it would be well worth while coming to terms with their usage.

Comment: Thank you so much Neil :) finally I am able to stop the stream. There is just only one thing left, the data event of stream only gets activated when a record is added in collection :( that means if no record is being added in db then I have no event where i can close the stream.. but you did answer my question of how to stop stream so thanks again

Comment: @Arian Your interpretation here is incorrect. The "stream" is just an object where an event listener is defined. Read though again and understand "scoping". As long as that object is scoped or otherwise accessible from somewhere else then you can either "pause" or just undefine the object so that nothing else ever happens.

Comment: I'll write down the steps how I check
1. I run my code 
2. mongod is running with vrebose option so i am able to see the monodb query which I have streamed
3. I again updated my code and added a function
    function clearStream(){
      setTimeout(function(){ stream.paused=true;  }, 10000);
    }
    if I put this function inside on('data') event it works but if I call this function simply outside... code does gets executed but nothing happens and I am able to see the query still running in mongod console :(

Comment: ok you were right, the function works from anywhere but only when any data is being received  in data event, I still need to figure out how I can make this work even when no data is received so I can stop stream query running in backgorund